# "Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time" error on lauching coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, android-mvvm

I get this error: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
It happens when I launch fun turnAllWordsOn() in the ViewModel (code below). This function launches coroutine, and I thought that coroutine always works on the backgroung thread. So why I get this error?
Apprecieate any help

In Fragment:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.action_turn_all_words_on -> {
            viewModel.turnAllWordsOn()
            true
        }
    // othes items
    }
```

In ViewModel:

```
fun turnAllWordsOn() = viewModelScope.launch {
    wordDao.turnAllWordsOn()
}
```

In Dao:

```
@Query("UPDATE word_table SET shown = 1")
fun turnAllWordsOn()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to mark your Dao function as a suspend function if you want Room to run it on a background thread. Otherwise all you're doing is calling a synchronous function from a coroutine scope.

```
@Query("UPDATE word_table SET shown = 1")
suspend fun turnAllWordsOn()
```

---

As a side note, suspend functions don't automatically run on a background thread, however Room does the necessary work behind the scenes when you mark a query as suspend.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you have the answer, I still want to give some solution and cause of the problem,
Performing networking, or accessing the database can block Ui Thread, so you can use

1. Using RxJava:

   Completable.fromAction {
   wordDao.turnAllWordsOn()
   }
2. Using Coroutine:

   @Query("UPDATE word_table SET shown = 1")
   suspend fun turnAllWordsOn()

Answer (score 1):

Just a note for anyone who ends up here the accepted answer is correct, however if you are calling a Dao function from an activity you must put in inside a Coroutine scope. So after you add suspend onto your Dao function call it from the activity like this.

```
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
    // call Dao function here
}
```